# Xampp: database connection refused

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm in the process of making a blog website and I'm using Xampp as my localhost service. When I tried to run my 'login.php" page it showed an error " Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: yes)" and then in order to fix that issue I changed my password in phpMyAdmin table and since then it is showing these couple of errors. I tried to edit my "config.inc.php" file too but it hasn't fixed the issue. Please help me out thanks.

```
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: the mysql server isn't running , look for the mysql error log and try to identify the error

Comment: Maybe port already in use. it can be by other applications or by same application in previous run.